# How to manage multiple tables, function, stored procedures and views (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012-express, sql-server-2012-datatools

I have multiple object in my database and i would like to list them give some description, accepted parameters and their types. The fastest way I know is to generate a database script and call it a day, but is there an easier way to archive this? I use Microsoft SSMS 2017 with SQL Server 2012.

Comment: select * from sys.objects ?

Comment: I would like to have something like</br>
Stored procedure "A":
@Input Arguments: Name nvarchar(30),</br>
                               Surname nvarchar(30),</br>
                                ID int </br>
TABLE VALUED FUNCTION "B"
Input:                  Name nvarchar(30),</br>
                               Surname nvarchar(30),</br>
                                ID int </br>
Output:                   City nvarchar(25)

Comment: What kind of SQL object is a Surname?

Comment: nvarchar(30)...

Comment: nvarchar(30) isn't an object, it's a datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the table `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS` (or `sys.parameters`).

Here is a simple query that extracts some of the data you requested; you can use this as a starting point and elaborate on this to get your desired output:

```
select P.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA,
   P.SPECIFIC_NAME, 
   R.ROUTINE_TYPE,
   P.PARAMETER_MODE,
   P.PARAMETER_NAME, 
   P.DATA_TYPE, 
   P.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS P
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES R ON P.SPECIFIC_CATALOG = R.ROUTINE_CATALOG 
   AND P.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = R.ROUTINE_SCHEMA 
   AND P.SPECIFIC_NAME = R.ROUTINE_NAME 
order by P.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA, P.SPECIFIC_NAME, P.PARAMETER_MODE, P.PARAMETER_NAME
```

Here is the output of this query on a simple database:

[image]

Comment: Wow I've never seen such SQL magic like that, guess I need to study this a lot.